# Why does the first time I land on Laravel URL it renders HTTP based on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using laravel 5.5 The application is being served on Elastic beanstalk single instance. I am able to server the Laravel application on HTTPS. However, when I first land on the link it serves as HTTP. IF I refresh the link it will again run on HTTPS. To test I cleared all the cookies and put the link on the address bar, again the first time I land there it serves in HTTP and again if I refresh the page it serves on HTTPS.

To serve the laravel app on Elastic Beanstalk I have already updated the SSL certificate.

Using the .htaccess as below

```
# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1
```

Additionally to serve all the pages on HTTPS I have included the code as below in the boot method of AppServiceProvider

```
\URL::forceScheme('https');
```

This is very annoying as I dont really get if it is the Laravel app problem or the server problem.

Comment: Are you editing .htaccess in root directory or public directory?

Comment: root directory ...

Answer (score 0):

You could configure your htaccess in root directory like this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} yourdomain\.com\.ar [NC]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com.ar/$1 [R,L]

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Please try this and let me know how it works :)

Comment: is .ar part of domain name?

Comment: No, .com.ar is an example i copied from one of our sites.